# How MPAndroidChart display all xaxis values

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm developing some chart features using MPAndroidChart library.

Is there any way to display all the xaxis values I added?
Seems that the library will auto calculate on xaxis, some of values will be hidden.
ex. display date: 05-17  05-17  05-15 ....
the same day 05-17 will not shown.

thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check out the [documentation of the XAxis](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/xaxis/).

And the method `setLabelsToSkip(...)`.
If you set that to 0, none of the labels in your x-axis will be skipped during rendering.

**Update v3.0.0**

As of this release, the x-axis is treated equally to the y-axis. If you want to display all labels, you can do so by using the `axis.setLabelCount(...)` method.

Comment: i cannot set any count.  i just want every x-axis labels to be shown. no lebel should be skipped. can i do that ?

Comment: I use axis.setLabelCount(4,true), but the x-axis still not showing.

Answer (score 2):

Get the number of items as an int from your dynamic list and use in setLabelCount